# EAFP vs LBYL: Which is more idiomatic Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

While I can find plenty on "[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) vs. [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)" for Python, I can't find any guidelines for Ruby. My own experience has been that Ruby supports exception handling at least as well as Python does, but my own experience is a drop in the bucket compared to the community at large.

So which paradigm is more idiomatic Ruby, EAFP or LBYL? Also, are there any significant performance issues to take into consideration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ruby community has no overall preference for LBYL or EAFP; it uses both in different idiomatic situations.

The Ruby community does not actually use the terms LBYL or EAFP; they're only used in the Python community as far as I know. But we can look at Ruby idioms and see how they fit those terms.

Ruby almost always uses LBYL when there is only one possible exceptional situation, such as an `Array` index out of bounds or an undefined `Hash` key. `nil` is returned in these situations. `nil` is an object and treated as false in conditionals, so it's less painful in Ruby than in some other languages to check for these situations; they can be handled succinctly by testing for truthiness or using `.try`.

What one almost never sees in Ruby (except where it bubbles up from preexisting standards) is the C-style LBYL pattern of returning an out-of-range value to indicate an exceptional condition, like returning -1 to indicate that a substring isn't contained in a string. Returning `nil` makes it harder for the caller to miss the exceptional condition.

Ruby is more likely to use EAFP

- when something would fail only if there were a programming error, such as calling a method with the wrong number of arguments or providing an object to a method which doesn't satisfy the interface expected by the method (i.e. doesn't have the right 'duck type'). There's no point in checking for these situations and trying to handle them gracefully; what would be the right thing to do?
- when there is complex information about the failure to return, such as the many ways that `File` operations or an ActiveRecord `save!` can fail.
- when the long-distance nature of `raise`/`rescue` is helpful, as in ActionController error handlers.

The relative performance of these styles is not an issue in the overwhelming majority of Ruby programs.

Comment: im gonna delete my answer because its clear i wasn't correct

Comment: Nice answer, @DaveSchweisguth, although I hope you don't mind if I wait a little while before accepting it. I certainly have noticed that the Ruby community doesn't use those terms, which is why I was forced to ask my question.

Comment: @maxpleaner I wish you had left your answer so I could give you an upvote for your effort. :C I'm sure I'll see you around though. :)